# Bootstrap 3 верстка 1 в 1 с psd

Tags: bootstrap, psd

Только начал переход с Bootstrap 2 на Bootstrap 3. Ничего трудного. Но здесь возникает вопрос: как верстать 1 в 1 с psd-макета, с помощью `col-md-` и `col-sx-`?

В версии Bootstrap 2 хотя бы было можно подогнать `<span>` сетку под себя.

А в новой версии как быть?

У меня такое впечатление, что все равно надо использовать свои стили для блоков, чтобы они соответствовали макету, а элементы сетки `col-md col-sx` нужны только для адаптивного дизайна, а точнее для различных дисплеев?

Answer (score 3):

1. В любом случае при обновлении проиходит изменение css, а это значит, что иногда немного надо менять вёрстку самого сайта
2. При большом обновлении, например с bootstrap 2 на bootstrap 3 есть тотальные изменения, например, изменение названий классов. Более подробно тут http://getbootstrap.com/migration/
3. Самое, на мой взгляд, полезное - познакомить дизайнера с особенностями bootstrap и, чтобы дизайнер максимально подстраивался под стандарты bootstrap'а
4. Максимально пользоваться стандартами bootstrap и минимально дописывать своего кода
   При соблюдении 3 правила будет легко верстать. Я понимаю что это не всегда возможно, но всё же.
   При соблюдении 4 правила обновлять версию bootstrap будем максимально легко.

Я некоторые проекты начинал на bootstrap 2, потом очень легко обновлялся. Потом пришло время обновления на 3 версию. Это было не легко, но и не сложно.
Все последние проекты делал на bootstrap 3, вообще никогда не было проблем с обновлением.